# Netty concurrency and "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: sockets, concurrency, nio, netty

I've built the following simple server, and I'm stress testing it using `ab`.
If I run `ab` making 3000 total request (300 concurrent) it works. If I run it again, it shows me:

```
apr_socket_connect(): Connection reset by peer (54)
```

And If after this error I try to make a single request with curl without restarting the server, it works. If I run again `ab` it shows the same error.
It seems that it can't handle too many concurrent connections. Below the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
                new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
            @Override
            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
                return Channels.pipeline(new StringEncoder(), new MyServerHandler());
            }
        });

        bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9090));
        System.out.println("Running");
}
```

Here is the handler:

```
public class MyServerHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

    private static AtomicLong request = new AtomicLong();

    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e)
            throws Exception {  
        ChannelFuture channelFuture = e.getChannel().write("This is request #" + request.incrementAndGet() + "\n");
        channelFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
        e.getChannel().close();
    }

}
```

As you see it's very simple, it just shows the total number of requests handled.
Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

'Connection reset by peer' usually means you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the other end. In other words, an application protocol error. You get the error itself on a *subsequent* read or write.

Comment: I don't get any exception by the server, and by reading the source code I've attached, I don't close the connection before I actually send the message. Please note that this problem only occurs under an high number of concurrent requests. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Mark I think you need to read my answer again. You are getting an exception somewhere otherwise you wouldn't be posting, and I did say 'closed by the other end'.

Comment: Matbe you can't open new socket. What does `ulimit -n` says?

Comment: @Slartibartfast He *has* opened the socket. That's how he got the connection that has been reset. This is different from 'connection refused', 'connection timed out', etc.

Comment: @EJP I am facing somehow related problem - with simple server load Netty complains about "Connection reset" from it's internals. This happens randomly, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. For 500 subsequent requests it does work in 10 cases of 10. For 1000 subsequent calls it fails with one connection reset and java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException. I do not close a channel explicitly in client code, so where is it closed? and why connection reset occurs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't immediately see anything wrong, but you could try the following to try to get more information:

1. Override `channelClosed` and output something so that you're 100% sure that Netty is *at least trying* to close the channel.
2. Use jvisualvm to have a look at the JVM running your server; you should be able to see the threads and whether they're active or not.
3. Write something to `System.out` server-side on `channelConnected` so you know that your connections have made it that far (especially for the 2nd run).
4. When you run `ab` the second time, is there an error for every connection attempt, or just for some?

What I find odd is that it seems to work the first time, but not thereafter. Keep in mind that this may not be a Netty - or even a JVM - issue, but rather the OS somehow limiting the the connection attempts.

I have done some tests with my own Netty test server, and found that starting large batches concurrent connections will produce an unpredictable outcome (most will connect, some will fail, but always a different ratio). As of yet I haven't figure out why that is (yet), but I suspect it is my OS refusing the connections rather than Netty.